# how to link html folder's file with php folder's file

Tags: php, html

I have 2 folders html and php, in html all html files exist and in php all php file exist.
In html folder-> buycars.html exist which link with viewh.php(this is in php folder)  how to create a link… I use

```
<a href="php/viewh.php">
```

that is not working.

Comment: If you are in the html folder you probably want: `<a href="../php/viewh.php"> `

Answer (score 0):

you need to jump one directory back

```
<a href="../php/viewh.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go up one directory. To do this you simply append `../` to your directory path;

```
<a href="../php/viewh.php">Click</a>
```

You can also go up multiple by stacking them like so;

```
<a href="../../directory/page.html">Click</a>
```

---

EDIT: @Sourabh beat me to it.